# Using Wcf Service Connecting Mscrm and Consuming it in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dynamics-crm

I am connecting mscrm to asp.net using wcf service but I'm unable to connect to asp.net. The error is:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>
> https://ags10.api.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl

could have any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to check the service URL at `Settings > Customizations > Developers Resources`.

It can be because of Multiple bindings. I have noticed that you are using https. With https I think have to include security certificate as well.

Please check the link bellow. Might be helpful for you: [Error: Metadata Contains A Reference That Cannot Be Resolved (CRM 2011 and 2013)](http://help.clickdimensions.com/error-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-crm-2011/)

[Link 2](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/96aece54-081d-40b2-b1c9-f55b55a06a72/metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-crm-2011?forum=crmdevelopment)

Comment: Actually,Dynamics crm online 2013 specific to Asia continent to crm5.In Dynamics crm 2014 there is no specific to crm5 it has only crm.url is like below:https://ags10.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc instead of that https://ags10.api.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc

Comment: Finally i found the answer.

Comment: I would recommend not to share your service url on this public platform. Please edit your comment. Someone can try to get into your system.